# nvd3 tickFormat is not working with reactjs

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am using `react` version `15.6.2` with `react-nvd3: ^0.5.7`
I have created a `multiBarChart`.
I want to change the `tickformat` of `Y-axis` as full integer. It is coming as float value.Please see attached image.
I want the numbers to be complete numbers not float values.

I used `tickFormat={d3.format('d')` this code to change tick format. But I am not able to do it yet.

My code is below:

```
<NVD3Chart
          id="barChart"
          type="multiBarChart"
          width={document.body.clientWidth-(document.body.clientWidth*0.13)}
          height={400}
          showLabel={false}
          stacked={true}
          showControls={true}
          showLegend={true}
          datum={this.state.activityOptions}
          color={['#3fceb1','#fff480']}
          x="label"
          y="values"
          reduceXTicks={false}
          tickFormat={d3.format('d')}/>
```

Can anyone help?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set tick formatting this way:

```
<NVD3Chart
  id="barChart"
  type="multiBarChart"
  width={document.body.clientWidth-(document.body.clientWidth*0.13)}
  height={400}
  showLabel={false}
  stacked={true}
  showControls={true}
  showLegend={true}
  datum={this.state.activityOptions}
  color={['#3fceb1','#fff480']}
  x="label"
  y="values"
  reduceXTicks={false}
  yAxis={{
    tickFormat: d3.format('d') // <== !!!
  }}
>
```

Check [the example sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/3y4qyno486).

Comment: It works. I was missing the correct format. Thanks alot @Mikhail Shabrikov